# How can I perform the web service/application only on https in node.js

Tags: node.js, security, https, methodology

I have a trivial question about web architecture. When I build a web service/application, I want to make it only work perfectly on https protocol.

Firstly I analyzed the google's methodology by network session of chrome developer tools. In there I found it, when a http request is sended to the google, that the request redirected to https of same origin.

I thought it is a respectable way. But I find it has a potential risk. When an authorized user using the google, he have a session. And after, he want to deep another site (e.g. Yahoo). And he will come back to the google by inserting the address 'google.com' directly in browser's address box. In this situation if the user didn't shut off the google session, in the redirect process, the unencrypted session token will be sended to google because the redirect process be proceeded on http protocol. So this user will be exposed MITM(man in the middle) attack.

So I hesitate to use google methodology. Anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [secure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies) flag on the session cookie. Then it won't ever be sent over HTTP.